# AWS Quicksight: Chart users by age group

Tags: amazon-quicksight

In AWS Quicksight, I want to be able to chart users by age group. I can do this in google data studio which looks like this.

[image]

wondering how do I make this happen in quicksight?

In Google Datastudio I created a calculated field using the CASE statement but I don't how to replicate in Quicksight.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used the "histogram" chart which is NOT the same as the "BAR" chart

[image]

[image]

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/histogram-charts.html